# Java: read hadoop reducer's output files

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I'm trying to read and analyze the mapreduce final output in hadoop. Below is part of the code in my "Job" file. I want to use FileSystem (Hadoop API) to read the output files, however, I have question regarding where to put the code highlighted in bold (between the double twin-stars). If I put it below system.exit, I'm afraid the code will be skipped.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        Configuration conf = new Configuration();
        String[] otherArgs = new GenericOptionsParser(conf, args)
                .getRemainingArgs();
        if (otherArgs.length != 3) {
            System.err.println("Usage: format is <in> <out> <keyword>");
            System.exit(2);
        }

        **Path distCache = new Path("/");
        String fileSys = conf.get("fs.default.name");
        HashMap<String, Integer> jobCountMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();**

        conf.set("jobTest", otherArgs[2]);
        Job job = new Job(conf, "job count");
        job.setJarByClass(JobResults.class);
        job.setMapperClass(JobMapper.class);
        job.setCombinerClass(JobReducer.class);
        job.setReducerClass(JobReducer.class);

        job.setOutputKeyClass(Text.class);
        job.setOutputValueClass(IntWritable.class);
        FileInputFormat.addInputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[0]));
        FileOutputFormat.setOutputPath(job, new Path(otherArgs[1]));

        distCache = new Path(args[2]);
  //      FileSystem fs = distCache.getFileSystem(conf); // for Amazon AWS
        if (fileSys.split(":")[0].trim().equalsIgnoreCase("s3n")) distCache = new Path("s3n:/" + distCache);

        FileSystem fs = FileSystem.get(conf);           // for local cluster

        Path pathPattern = new Path(distCache, "part-r-[0-9]*");
        FileStatus[] list = fs.globStatus(pathPattern);

        for (FileStatus status : list)
        {
//          DistributedCache.addCacheFile(status.getPath().toUri(), conf);
            try {
            BufferedReader brr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(status.getPath().toString()));
                            String line;
                while ((line = brr.readLine()) != null)
                {
                    String[] resultsCount = line.split("\\|");
                    jobCountMap.put(resultsCount[0], Integer.parseInt(resultsCount[1].trim()));
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e)
            {
               e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        System.out.println("the size of Hashmap is: " + jobCountMap.size());
        System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a fairly easy solution to the System.exit problem. Where you had:

```
 System.out.println("the size of Hashmap is: " + jobCountMap.size());
    System.exit(job.waitForCompletion(true) ? 0 : 1);
```

Instead place the following:

```
System.out.println("the size of Hashmap is: " + jobCountMap.size());
boolean completionStatus = job.waitForCompletion(true);

//your code here

if(completionStatus==true){
    System.exit(0)
}else{
    System.exit(1)
}
```

This should allow you to run any processing you want within your main function, including starting a second job if you want.